# Why does the time-date for document set members differ from the document set time-date after a move

Tags: designer-workflow, date-time, document-set, sharepoint-designer

When moving a document set from one library to a Records library via a modified ootb approval SP2010 workflow, the docset has the correct CST date and time, but its document set members are 6 hours premature.  CST requires a 6hr adjustment to GMT. Is this a bug in the SPD "move" command or could this be an incorrect configuration setting?